# Don't know how to approach this algorithm analysis problem...

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

"Consider a queue implemented using two stacks (in_stack and out_stack). Analyze the worst-case running times of its enqueue and dequeue methods, and express them using ”Big-Oh” notation."

```
function enqueue(o)
    in_stack.push(o)

function dequeue()
    while not in_stack.isEmpty() do
        out_stack.push(in stack.pop())
    if out_stack.isEmpty() then
        throw QueueEmptyException
    return obj ← out_stack.pop()
    while not out_stack.isEmpty() do
        in_stack.push(out stack.pop())
    return return_obj
```

Thus far I only understand how to analyze worst-case running time by counting primitive operations, and I cannot figure out how to apply that method to this problem. Do I need to use amortized analysis? I've watched several videos on both the accounting method and the potential method and I still cannot grasp either of them or how to apply them in this situation. Any help/hint is appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: My question leans more towards dequeue because I'm pretty sure enqueue is simply O(1), but someone please let me know if I am incorrect here.

Comment: Can you follow how the algorithm works? How many things does it do? How many more things would it do when you double the stack size? Here you can consider stack.push, stack.pop and stack.isEmpty as "things" (primitive O(1) operations).

Comment: Assuming that the stack is implemented efficiently and that pushing and popping from a stack is a constant time operation in the worst case then you have answered enqueue. Can you explain in plain language what the dequeue method is doing? Hint: a queue is FIFO and a stack is LIFO which means elements put in a stack are in the wrong end of the stack to be retrieved as the would in a queue.